# Uilabel is not visible in collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Im using the following code to load images from url into collection view

-

```
 (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *recipeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];


    if ([ImageArray count] >0){
    for(int i = 0; i < [ImageArray count]; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                recipeImageView.image = image;
            });
        });
    }
    }else{
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)];
        title.text = @"No image record found";
        title.tag = 200;
        [title setHidden:true];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
    }

    [spinnerShow stopAnimating];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    return cell;
}
```

If the ImageArray has got some url, if loop will be executed. Else the else loop will be executed where it will display a label saying no image record found. But the uilabel is not getting visible

Comment: The label isn't visible because you are hiding it with `[title setHidden:true];`.

Comment: still its not visible even after removing it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using for loop in cellForItemAtIndexPath? This method is called for every item in UICollectionView. In else condition, add log or breakpoint and check if it is going there or always going in if condition. Make sure if you need to check for array count or want to check if image exists on URL?